# Datetime values chopped in RSQLite depending on null values

Tags: r, sqlite, datetime, rsqlite, r-dbi

I am confronted with a weird phenomenom when extracting data out of a SQLite 3 database using the RSQLite 1.0.0 package. All except the year of the datetime value gets truncated!

See an example:

Following I am extracting a DATETIME column:

```
library(RSQLite)
src_path <- "../DataLocked/Study.db"
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), src_path)
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT Todesdatum FROM Kontraindikation LIMIT 10")
```

This gets me the following result:

```
        Todesdatum
   1          NA
   2          NA
   3        2004
   4          NA
   5        2006
   6          NA
   7          NA
   8          NA
   9          NA
   10         NA
```

Now from the same table I am omitting NON NULL values:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT Todesdatum FROM Kontraindikation WHERE Todesdatum NOTNULL")
```

This gets me the following result:

```
            Todesdatum
1  2004-09-16 00:00:00
2  2006-04-20 00:00:00
3  2006-06-02 00:00:00
4  2007-09-15 00:00:00
5  2008-06-12 00:00:00
6  2005-10-04 00:00:00
7  2008-11-22 00:00:00
8  2005-12-22 00:00:00
9  2006-11-05 00:00:00
10 2006-02-08 00:00:00
...
```

Now I try to do a string format on the DATETIME field:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d',Todesdatum) as fixed_Todesdatum FROM Kontraindikation 10")
```

That works:

```
        fixed_Todesdatum
   1          <NA>
   2          <NA>
   3       2004-09-16
   4          <NA>
   5       2006-04-20
   6          <NA>
   7          <NA>
   8          <NA>
   9          <NA>
   10         <NA>
```

I have really no idea what is going on and how to solve this.
I would be very thankful for any pointers.

Greetings,
Alex

Comment: Unlike other RDMS's, there is no [datetime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm) storage class in SQLite3 *but SQLite is capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL or INTEGER values*. So is the column a numeric or string type?

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. The data type is in all columns TEXT.

Comment: What is the problem? What is your desired result? Wouldn't the last query work?

Comment: The desired output is actually 'YY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'. This is also the correct behavior. However, if NULL values exists in the table it seems to the RSQLite driver chops everythings except the year. I am pretty sure it is a RSQLite bug. I did quite alot if research before asking this question here - I just wanted to make sure I did not make a mistake. Or maybe somebody else has made this observation before. I will submit it now as an Issue on GitHub. Thanks very much for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Current `RSQLite` is a bit weak when it comes to the detection of the data type. Unlike most DBMS, SQLite can store [arbitrary data types in each entry of a column](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

You didn't submit a reproducible example, but I was able to replicate the problem:

```
library(tibble)
library(DBI)

a <- tibble(a = c(NA_integer_), b = 1)
b <- tibble(a = c("2014-06-04 00:00:00"), b = 2)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "test", a)
dbWriteTable(con, "test", b, append = TRUE)

dbReadTable(con, "test")
```

The two data frames have different data types for the `a` column, by writing `a` first this column is created as `INTEGER`. If I change `NA_integer_` to `NA_character`, the problem vanishes. Can you replicate this?

It could be that your `Todesdatum` column has `INTEGER` or `REAL` affinity, which tricks `RSQLite` into believing that the first value is a number. Update the column affinity, or use your `strftime` workaround with your desired formatting.

Anyway, I agree that RSQLite should do a better job here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I can replicate your code. I tried to change the type affinity. It does not work. Problem is the NULL value. typeof(NULL) is NULL and I cannot change the affinity for NULL values. I will work with the strftime workaround until the problem is solved. Anyway, thank you so much for your effort and the great package!